# cordova-plugin-secure-key-store throughs error for --prod build

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic2, keystore, ionic3

I am using this [keyStore](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-secure-key-store) cordova plugin in my ionic3 project.

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-secure-key-store
```

Everything works fine when i use `ionic cordova run android`

but when i do `ionic cordova run android --prod --device` or `ionic cordova run android --prod` i am getting error as below

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'SecureKeyStore' of undefined

Update:

app.component.ts file

```
setUserDetails() {

    cordova.plugins.SecureKeyStore.get((res) => {
      console.log(res); // res - string retrieved 
      this.email = res;

      cordova.plugins.SecureKeyStore.get((res) => {
        console.log(res); // res - string retrieved 
        this.password = res;

        cordova.plugins.SecureKeyStore.get( (res) => {
          console.log(res); // res - string retrieved 
          this.access_token = res;
          if (this.email && this.password && this.access_token) {
            console.log("invoing tabs page")
            this.rootPage = "Tabs";
          } else {
            this.rootPage = "LoginPage";
          }

        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.rootPage = "LoginPage";
        }, "access_token");

      }, (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.rootPage = "LoginPage";
      }, "password");

    }, (error) => {
      this.rootPage = "LoginPage";
      console.log(error);
    }, "email");

  }
```

Note: i have also used set method and get method for string the above value.

Comment: can you add the code where you access this?

Comment: @suraj kindly check my updated question

Comment: did you try using this.platform.ready()?

Comment: i am calling the above function inside my platform ready